# NullPointer in an Class array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I have two java classes.  Schedule is the main class that uses an array of Jobs called `deadline`.  I'm having problems putting anything in array.  I have a for loop that reads data from a text file (it works fine) and inserts certain data into `deadline`.  I not successfully creating `deadline` because whenever I want to start inserting into the array I get a `NullPointerException`.  (The code below the `...` obviously isn't what I actually coded, but it is still the same situation.)

It has been a while since I've coded in Java, so I might be just overlooking something simple, but I'm not really sure what it could be...  Thanks for any help you can give.

```
public class Schedule {

    private Job []deadline;
    Schedule (int n){
        Job[] deadline = new Job[n];
    }

    ...
        int n = 7;
        Schedule schedule = new Schedule(n);

        deadline[0] = new Job("A",3,40); // This line won't compile. NullPointerException
}


public class Job {

    private String name;
    private int deadline;
    private int profit;

    Job(String n, int d, int p){
        name = n;
        deadline = d;
        profit = p;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are shadowing `deadline` in your constructor, so you don't initialize the class member `deadline`, but the local one. Change it to:

```
    private Job []deadline;
    Schedule (int n){
        deadline = new Job[n];
    // ^^ note - no Job[] here
    }
```

Comment: In other words, deadline gets declared by the class, so you don't need to re-declare it inside the constructor.  By doing so, you're actually creating a new variable (with the same name) that only exists inside your constructor.

Comment: *facepalm*  I figured it was something stupid like that.  Thanks, man.  It works now!

Comment: happened to all of us :) glad I could help.